# Power switch for 1 wire bridge DS2484 loads i2c bus

Tags: i2c, 1-wire

I am using a DS2484 chip to add one wire communication to my device. This chip is a bridge between i2c on the MCU side and 1W on the sensor side. I have other sensors on the i2c bus. My device is very low power so a 3 uA sleep current is way too much. In order to mitigate this I designed a MOSFET power switch for the chip instead of using the sleep pin. I tied the VDD and SLPZ pin together to say that as soon as I engage the power switch and energize the chip I want it to go active, never to enter sleep mode. This does, however, not seem to work very well... Unless I pull VCC for the 1W IC high, my i2c bus is loaded when I try to talk to other sensors.

Does this seem like expected behaviour? Am I missing something in how I think I can use this? Can anyone spot issues?

The current workaround is to use high drive strength on the MCU pins (nrf52840, 5 mA). Any comments on how reasonable that is? Seems to break the specification IMO...

IC datasheet: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2484.pdf

Edit: Please see note 10 on page 4 of the datasheet: "The DS2484 does not obstruct the SDA and SCL lines if SLPZ is at 0V or if VCC is switched off."

[image: Ilustrative schematic]

Scope readings when talking to another sensor on the i2c bus:
[image: loaded]
[image: ic on, more normal]
[image: workaround]

Edit: As per request, here is a measurement that shows both 1wire vdd and io during failed i2c coms. They are indeed both low.
[image: SDA & 1W VDD]

Comment: I have deleted my answer since I did not notice note 10 in the datasheet. I took the liberty of editing your comment into your question.

Comment: I bet the circuit you show may not be the problem, it may be somewhere else. What's on the onewire IO pin? Have you measured what's on chip OW IO pin and VDD pin? Maybe Note 10 does not apply, maybe VCC is not off or SLPZ is not 0V?

Comment: @DoxyLover I did find your comment useful on the general level, but perhaps you are correct that it does not fit this context. Thanks for the edit update.

Comment: @Justme perhaps the problem is elsewhere, but I'd like to look at this a bit more here.

There was nothing on the 1Wbus at the time of the scope readings. I could measure the VDD pin just to verify that it is indeed off, but I'd be surprised if that was not the case. Will report back during the day.

Comment: @Justme I edited and added a measurement showing 1W VDD to stay low during other i2c messages.

Comment: @OhmInpw OK, what about the onewire data bus? And to what state the chip is set before powering it down?

Comment: @Justme Sorry. I updated my new image with one that has io as well. It too is low.

Comment: @OhmInpw If shutting down the chip causes problems, the current would have to leak somewhere and slow rise time should mean there is a capacitor that charges from it. Are you absolutely sure about your scope settings (you should never use 1x probe setting unless you know what you are doing). Set all probes and scope to 10x, make sure all channels are DC coupled, etc. There must be voltage somewhere when this happens.

Comment: I just tried the nuke option and unsoldered the IC, now my other i2c sensor works just fine.
Re. the 1 vs 10x it's not the issue. There was a use case for 1x next to me (small vibrations). I tried all this with 10x as well.

Comment: To clarify, I have hundreds of this board with the same issue and unsoldering was just to test on one, I'm still trying to understand the root cause here.